# Google map not working in android app via appium + selenium (Java)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, selenium, appium

SO I have an Android app which has Google maps implemented in it. While running the app via appium map is never loaded and the screens loads forever.

Manually it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem too. Apparently it's because Appium resigns the apk with another certificate which is not bound to google maps.

Best way to get around this is to install the application via a Beta release on the Play store and then set the capabilities in appium so that it does not reinstall the application but instead uses the existing one.

You can do this by removing the --app capability and setting the --app-pkg one to the application you want to test. Then make sure you have --no-reset set to true and your --deviceName set and you should be good to go.

You can also set the --appActivity but I've found it works fine without the need of setting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting geoLocation in driver:

```
    private AndroidDriver setupGeoLocation(AndroidDriver driver, GeoLocations geoLocation) {

        driver.setLocation(new Location(geoLocation.getLatitude(), geoLocation.getLongitude(), geoLocation.getAltitude()));

        Log.system(sessionInfo, "Setting driver to GeoLocation for '" + geoLocation.toString() + "' (latitude: " + geoLocation.getLongitude() + "), (longitude: " + geoLocation.getLongitude() + ")");

        return driver;
}
```

just ignore GeoLocations, its just enum in code, all You need is this line:

```
driver.setLocation(new Location(double lat, double long, double alt));
```

I had similar issue and it helped.

Comment: I tried the same for appium, but the location is not set in my application. I used Appium driver and code as follows driver.setLocation(new Location(10.79,78.70, 1000));